# Run a function before all the test modules in Vitest

Tags: node.js, testing, vitest

I am using `Vitest` as my testing framework in a project.

I have multiple test files in the project, let's say `A.spec.ts` and `B.spec.test`. I am using the standard `test` script (`vitest run --no-threads --coverage`) to test my code. I want to run a certain function (to purge and clean the testing database), before and after all the test suites are run (i.e. before all the tests in `A.spec.ts` and `B.spec.ts`, and after them as well).

Is there any way to achieve the same? I read about the methods like `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, but they work in the context of a file, and thus do not help with my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try `global setup`

[globalsetup](https://vitest.dev/config/#globalsetup)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a setup file in the directory of your likings (e.g. `/tests/setup.ts`)

Then, you need to link this file in the vitest config. For example, if your vitest config file is `vitest.config.ts` then it should look something like this:

```
export default defineConfig({
    test: {
      setupFiles: ['/tests/setup.ts'],
      ...
```

Finally, in your setup.ts (or whatever is your file), you call the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` method, just like you would in any of your tests:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // Do something here
})

afterEach(() => {
  // Do something here
})
```

This works on `vitest` **v0.32.2** don't know about earlier versions.

Comment: You can also add context to the setup and teardown methods. Later, you can access the context variables inside the unit test cases. See documentation: https://vitest.dev/guide/test-context.html#beforeeach-and-aftereach

Comment: It doesn't answer the original question, but helps me with mine. Thank you! :)